# error response node js api

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api

I'm creating a node JS API (ES6) the app is using google firebase for auth db and more.
I'm trying to sent the client a response back we there is an error like an invalid password I search a bit and I tried some things people say and no success.

EDIT:

I have edited the route so it will be like that
now getting the error response but not with the response text i sent

in the route file I have:

```
app.route('/signin')
.post(auth.SignIn , function(req ,res) {
});
```

on the controller I have:

```
    exports.SignIn = function(req, res) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  console.log(req.body.email + " - Attempting To SignIn");

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode + " - " + errorMessage);
    res.send(error.message);
  });

  console.log(email + " - Is Signed In - ");
}
```

on the client:

```
  $("#signinform").submit(function(event) {
    alert("test");
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
      'email': $('input[name=ident]').val(),
      'password': $('input[type=password]').val()
    };


    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost:3000/signin",
      data: formData,
      success: function(res){
        alert(res);
      },
      error: function(res){
        alert(res);
      }
    });

  });
```

when the log in is incorrect I get the error on the node.js console from this line:

```
console.log(errorCode + " - " + errorMessage);
```

if any one knows how to fix this I will be very happy :)
Thanks.

Comment: Couple of things I notice, you are not handling the success part of the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` promise to send back a `res.sendStatus(200)` and from what I can see, you should be getting the `console.log(email + " - Is Signed In - ");` as well (because it will execute it regardless of what happens to the login).
Could you maybe post the actual error message that you are getting? Might simply be a invalid login attempt error

Comment: the console.log(email + " - Is Signed In - "); does not really matter because i want to send the error back to the client that line outputs to the node js console not the client
for the actual error 
the line console.log(errorCode + " - " + errorMessage); is printing it to the node js console it will be :
auth/invalid-email - The email address is badly formatted.
or some thing similar 
i just want to sent this text back to the clientt html/js page

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you could fix it trying:

```
app.post('/signin',SignIn(req,res))
```

Comment: i have added that like that:      app.route('/signin')
    .post(auth.SignIn , function(req ,res) {
      console.log(res.error + " " + res)
    });   
now im getting an error response but without the presponse text i sent